# Show that it is possible to color the edges of $K_n$ with at most $3 \sqrt n$ colors so that there are no monochromatic triangles.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

> Show that it is possible to color the edges of $K_n$ with at most $3 \sqrt n$ colors so that there are no monochromatic triangles.

(This was previous question and I get an explanation in the comments: *Does this problem make a sense? I would expect at least, not at most. Where is my thinking wrong?*)

Here is a solution: Actually, the problem is trivial. Proceed inductively.

Just split $K_n$ in to two parts with ${n\over 2}$ elements in both if $n$ is even or ${n-1\over 2}$ and ${n+1\over 2}$ elements if $n$ is odd. Color all edges between this parts with one color. In one part we will not use more than $3\sqrt{n+1\over 2}$ colors. So we have used $$3\sqrt{n+1\over 2} +1$$ colors and all we have to check if $$3\sqrt{n+1\over 2} +1\leq 3\sqrt{n}$$ which is true.

---

Since I found this [here, problem 41](http://yufeizhao.com/pm/ps.pdf) I wonder how to solve it with a *probabilistic method*?

Comment: With "at least" it would be trivial, you would give each edge a different color and voila. The point is how to do it using a small number of colors.

Comment: Let $n=16$. You want to ask: is it possible to color the edges of $K_{16}$ with at least $12$ colors and have no monochromatic triangles. Sure, we color each edge with a different color and we used $120$ colors, which is at least $12$, so problem solved. If you ask can we do it with at most $12$ colors it becomes more interesting.

Comment: But you can not color $K_{16}$ with two colors to not having monocolor triangle. Can you? @MichalAdamaszek

Comment: You should find a coloring with some number of colors less than $3\sqrt{n}$, not with every possible number of colors less than $3\sqrt{n}$. For example coloring  $K_{16}$ with $4$ colors solves the problem for $n=16$.

Comment: Exactly. Two colours would not be enough. You need more than 2. Try to be economical, as if colours were "expensive". What's the best deal you can get ?

Comment: Here is a long formulation. Prove that for every integer $n$ there exists an integer $k$ such that $k\leq 3\sqrt{n}$ and such that the edges of $K_n$ can be colored with exactly $k$ colors and without monochomatic triangles.

Comment: Thanks @MichalAdamaszek

Comment: I wonder why the problem is stated for $3\sqrt{n}$ colors, when a simple construction (actually the one you found) uses only $\left\lceil\log_2n\right\rceil$ colors which is much smaller than $3\sqrt n$. Evidently some other method is expected.

Comment: In other words, the edges of a complete graph on $2^n$ vertices can (rather obviously) be colored with $n$ colors so that there are no monochromatic triangles.

Comment: Just because you have a solution does not make the problem "trivial".

Comment: @MishaLavrov It is not because I have a solution, it is because there is much better bound.

Comment: @MishaLavrov why did you say what you said? aqua never said that that was why he/she said it was trivial. he/she just called it trivial....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $3\sqrt{n}$ colors. For each edge, choose one of those $3\sqrt{n}$ colors uniformly at random to color it with, with the random choice being independent for each edge.

The probability a given three vertices form a monochromatic triangle is $(\frac{1}{3\sqrt{n}})^2 = \frac{1}{9n}$.

The number of triangles whose three edge colorings are not independent of a given triangle is $3n-8$ (the triangle itself and the at most $n-3$ triangles sharing a given edge of the given triangle).

It holds that $e\frac{1}{9n}(3n-7) \le 1$, so by [Lemma II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_local_lemma), there is a nonzero probability that there are no monochromatic triangles, as wanted.

Comment: Can you tell me please, why is 2. senence true. Is not it on $^3$?

Comment: @Aqua If $k$ is the number of colours, the probability that a given triangle has all $3$ edges of a **specified** colour is $1/k^3$; the probability that all $3$ edges are the **same** colour (any colour) is $1/k^2$. (If I toss $3$ coins, the probability that they all come up heads is $1/8$, the probability that they all come up tails is $1/8$, but the probability that they all **match** is $1/4$.)

Comment: So we have event $A_i$ ...i-th triangle is monochromatic, and we want to see what is a probability that none of it occurs? @bof

Comment: This is very nice solution. And I would say this is pretty much straightforward proof, geedy. You just have to know LLL to check how much that greedines cost you.

Comment: Do you know a solution without LLL?

Comment: @Aqua Well, I don't know another way to prove that the random coloring works for $3\sqrt{n}$ colors (you certainly can't argue in the most trivial way without using LLL), if that's what you're asking. If you're asking if there's another way to randomly color whose proof of success with $3\sqrt{n}$ colors is possible without LLL, then we're getting into weird territory, since you already found a deterministic coloring.

Comment: @Aqua No problem. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know any other not so complicated problems acessable to high school students which can be solved by LLL

Comment: @Aqua I'm a bit confused. I don't think high school students know LLL. Do you mean the statement is accessible to high school students? Or do you mean the statement is and there is an elementary proof, as well as an LLL proof, like for this problem?

Comment: For your previous question, I think most problems involving LLL have elementary statements. You could probably find some more in Noga Alon's "probabilistic method" book. For the question you just asked, I don't really know what you are asking.

Comment: Eh, sorry, it was wrong link. This one https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1819134p13025747

Comment: @Aqua Sorry for late response. Lovasz Local Lemma is only helpful for proofs, i.e. proving that a certain randomized coloring (for example) gets the bounds one wants. In the case of the question you linked to, a pure random coloring of subsets most certainly will *not* work. Why should it? If you're randomly coloring the subsets, then the colors of the individual numbers don't matter at all, so around $\frac{n}{2}$ colors will be bad with very high probability.

Comment: But it is used only 2 colors...? I also posted it here if you are interested https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3336974/color-each-subset-of-1-2-ldots-n-either-red-or-blue-so-that-each-red-numb?noredirect=1#comment6867581_3336974

Comment: @Aqua So? An individual number (say 1) has the same odds as being in more red subsets than blue subsets as it does being in more blue subsets than red subsets. So each individual number will have probability roughly $\frac{1}{2}$ of being bad. So there's no way this random coloring will work. Or am I missing something?