# Color each subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ either red or blue so that each red number lies in more red subsets than blue subsets...

Tags: combinatorics, probabilistic-method

> A positive integer $n > 2$ is chosen, and each of the
>   numbers $1, 2, \dots, n$ is colored red or blue. Show that it is
>   possible to color each subset of $N=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ either red
>   or blue so that each red number lies in more red subsets than blue
>   subsets, and each blue number lies in more blue subsets than red
>   subsets.

**Attempt of solving**

Say element of $N$ is *bad*, if it lies in at most sets of its color as of the sets pf oposite color.

Randomly color each set $N$. As we have 
$2^n$ set, we have $2^{2^n}$ different colorings. Take an arbitrary $m$ from $N$, say it is blue and claculate probabilty it is bad.  We have $2^{n-1}$ sets with $m$, so we have at least $2^{n-2}$ red set. So some coloring is bad for $m$ if we have

- $0$ blue and $2^{n-1}$ red sets with $m$, so the number of colorings in this case is $${2^{n-1}\choose 0} \cdot 2^{2^{n-1}}$$
- $1$ blue and $2^{n-1}-1$ red sets with $m$, so the number of colorings in this case is  $${2^{n-1}\choose 1} \cdot 2^{2^{n-1}}$$
- $2$ blue and $2^{n-1}-2$ red sets with $m$, so the number of colorings in this case is  $${2^{n-1}\choose 2} \cdot 2^{2^{n-1}}$$

  $$\vdots $$
- $2^{n-2}$ blue and $2^{n-2}$ red sets with $m$, so the number of colorings in this case is  $${2^{n-1}\choose 2^{n-2}} \cdot 2^{2^{n-1}}$$

So the number of all bad colorings for $m$ is $$ \sum
_{i=0}^{2^{n-2}}{2^{n-1}\choose i} \cdot 2^{2^{n-1}} = {1\over 2}
\Big(2^{2^{n-1}} + {2^{n-1}\choose 2^{n-2}} \Big)\cdot
2^{2^{n-1}}$$ so the probability $m$ is bad is: $$P =
{2^{2^{n-1}} + {2^{n-1}\choose 2^{n-2}} \over 2\cdot
2^{2^{n-1}}}$$ So the probability that at least one elements is bad in bounded by :
$$n\cdot {2^{2^{n-1}} + {2^{n-1}\choose
2^{n-2}} \over 2\cdot  2^{2^{n-1}}}$$
which is clearly more than 1 so the union bound does not apply here.

**I was wondering if Lovasz local lemma can be aplied here? Any help?**

Comment: I'd be tempted to try induction.  Assuming I've solved the problem for the same colors on the first $n-1$ integers.  Now we add in $n$ colored, say, blue. All we need to do is to color one more than half the subsets containing $n$ blue.  Can I not do this evenly for all the other elements?  The subset consisting of $n$ alone will be blue, so I just need to be $50-50$ for all the others.

Comment: The problem of course is that there is an odd number of subsets containing $n$, and excluding $(n)$.  So we can't get $50-50$ exactly.  If, in my prior coloring, every number was only ahead by one in the count, this would cause a problem.  So the inductive statement needs to ensure that at least one element is ahead by at least two.  Happily, the construction ensures that $n$ will end up at least two ahead so there is still hope.

Comment: What is a *red subset*? Is it a subset where at least half of the elements are colored red?

Comment: No, arbitrary subset can be red, there is no rule to color a subset. Coloring of elements and set are not connected. @Mike

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't expect a naive application of the local lemma to work, because:

- In a uniformly random coloring, the probability that a number is contained in more red sets than blue sets is a constant: approximately $\frac12$.
- However, the number of dependencies is not constant: it grows exponentially with $n$.

In fact, the high probability of failure is an obstacle with any probabilistic coloring method.

---

A deterministic coloring works. Suppose $R$ is the set of red elements and $B$ is the set of blue elements. Begin by coloring a set $S$ red if $|R \cap S| > \frac12|R|$, and blue otherwise. The quality of the result depends on the parity of $r := |R|$.

- When $r$ is odd, red elements are ahead by $\binom{r-1}{(r-1)/2}2^{n-r}$ of the sets containing them, and blue elements have an equal number of red and blue sets that contain them.
- When $r$ is even, red elements have an equal number of red and blue sets that contain them, and blue elements are ahead by $\binom{r}{r/2}2^{n-r}$ of the sets containing them.

Ties are bad, so in either case, we'll have to fix the coloring slightly. When $r$ is odd (and $r \ne n$, so blue elements exist), boost blue elements by $1$ by coloring the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ blue instead of red.

When $r$ is even, or if the previous step brought the red elements down to an even split (which happens for instance if $r=1$ and $n=2$), boost red elements by $1$ by coloring each singleton set $\{x\}$ for $x \in R$ red, instead of blue. This is a free action: it doesn't hurt blue elements at all, but gives red elements the boost they needed.

Comment: When $r$ is odd, do you mean to color $\{1, 2, \dots, n-1\}$ blue or to color $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ blue?  What if $n$ is blue?

Comment: @saulspatz I mean $\{1,2, \dots,n\}$. I don't know why I wrote $n-1$.